# Employers discussing my work with parents

Tags: communication, employer-relations, conflict, employer

I currently work at a bar/pub that I don't intend staying in for the rest of my life. My parents are locals at this pub and now my employers are discussing my work with my parents and I never hear the end of it when we are in the house. My employers never discuss anything with me though, can anything be done?

I'm 22

Comment: Use your pay to move out of your parents house?

Comment: I am on nowhere near enough money to move out. I'd just like my parents not to get involved, I'm not in school anymore, it's not teacher parent conference day

Comment: Your employer is acting unprofessionally IMO. They should not be discussing your work with your parents at all, much less discussing it with them and *not* with you.

Comment: What is it that you never hear the end of? Change your job, or change that behavior.

Comment: Have you told your employers you don't like them discussing this with your parents? That's supposed to be personal information.

Comment: Are your parents friends with your boss/manager?

Comment: I'm surprised that this doesn't have any close votes, what exactly is the question here?

Comment: They've only recently become friends and it seems like  G only thing they talk about is me. I've told my parents not to talk to them about me and they keep saying that they want to best for me, I need them to understand that I don't need them watching my back 24/7

Comment: I think it's important that you get your parents to understand that hearing about your performance at work through the 'broken telephone' of hearsay from them *is not what's best for you*. If they truly do want what's best for you, they should be encouraging your employer to talk to you directly.

Answer (score 16):

> can anything be done?

This seems unlikely, it seems your parents have a long standing and friendly relationship with the owners which quite possibly influenced you getting employment there. But even if it didn't you cannot stop the owners and your parents from talking to each other about you.

What you can do is tell your parents you don't like it and you'd appreciate them not getting involved in conversations with the owner about your work, and tell the owner you'd rather not be getting an earbashing from your parents every week so if they don't mind keeping your working life a bit more between you and them it would be great.

Quite often just letting people (especially those who love you) know that you're uncomfortable with their behaviour is enough to trigger a change. Sometimes works with total strangers as well.